# Is it possible to use pipe in typescript component or service class?

Tags: angular

In v15 I bootstrap the app component using `bootstrapApplication`.

Inside the `ts` I import `AppHeaderComponent` and write it in `imports` section.
The `AppHeaderComponent` inject  `foo = inject(FooService);` .
The `FooService` is inject `BazPipe`.
`BazPipe` is contain the following pipe (with standalone is true):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'baz',
  standalone: true,
})
export class BazPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor() {}

  transform(value) {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Why angular throw error in the console?

```
ERROR
Error: R3InjectorError(Environment Injector)[FooService -> BazPipe -> BazPipe]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for BazPipe!
```

[stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pvsaa6?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fheader.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ffoo.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fbaz.pipe.ts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to resolve pipe using dependency injection you need to provide BazPipe as provider in root component

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent,{  providers:[BazPipe]});
```

**[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w9xuyq?file=src/main.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `pipe` as `injectable` service class. `Pipe` is like the component class, should be used directly in place and does not participate in DI. But you can do this for use `pipe` everywhere in code with a static method:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'baz',
  standalone: true,
})
export class BazPipe implements PipeTransform {
  static transform(value) {
    return value;
  }

  transform(value) {
    return BazPipe.transform(value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You CAN use pipe in DI, you just need to provide them in module, but I wouldn't suggest you that because there are big issue with pipe providers: they can't be `providedIn: 'root'`. Why is this a problem, if you could just provide the pipe in your root module? Well, after you providing something manually in root module this thing will not be tree-shacked and will be always in your main.js bundle.

So there are 2 possible solutions:

- Create static method in your pipe and use this static method where you need in your code (as was mentioned by [Anton Marinenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11248646/anton-marinenko)).
- Move pipe logic to a service and use this service in components and other services.

I should also mention that I have faced the same problem with Angular `CurrencyPipe` which I wanted to use in my service that is `providedIn: 'root'` since `CurrencyPipe` has no static method or service I've ended up providing this pipe in my app.module.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` to the pipe and use it as a service.